# NN works with simple problems but not with MNIST numbers

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, python

I have been working on a NN with one hidden layer with a flexible amount of nodes in each of the three layers. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

class_names = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

class NeuralNetwork():

    correct = 0
    num_predictions = 10
    epochs = 5
    Lambda = 10
    learningRate = 0.005

    def __init__(self, sizes, sizeOfEpoch):
        self.sizeOfEpoch = sizeOfEpoch 
        self.dimensions = sizes

        self.secondLayerNeurons = np.empty(sizes[1])
        self.outputNeurons = np.empty(sizes[2])

        self.firstLayerWeights = np.random.rand(sizes[1], sizes[0])
        self.secondLayerWeights = np.random.rand(sizes[2], sizes[1])
        self.firstLayerBiases = np.random.rand(sizes[1])
        self.secondLayerBiases = np.random.rand(sizes[2])

        self.firstLayerWeightsSummations = np.zeros([sizes[1], sizes[0]])
        self.secondLayerWeightsSummations = np.zeros([sizes[2], sizes[1]])
        self.firstLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros([sizes[1]])
        self.secondLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros([sizes[2]])

        self.hiddenLayerErrors = np.empty(sizes[1])
        self.outputLayerErrors = np.empty(sizes[2])

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

    def sigmoidDerivative(self, x):
        return np.multiply(x,(1-x))

    def forwardProp(self, inputs):
        for i in range (self.dimensions[1]):
            self.secondLayerNeurons[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.firstLayerWeights[i], inputs)+self.firstLayerBiases[i])
        for i in range (self.dimensions[2]):
            self.outputNeurons[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.secondLayerWeights[i], self.secondLayerNeurons)+self.secondLayerBiases[i])

    def backProp(self, inputs, correct_output):
        self.outputLayerErrors = np.subtract(self.outputNeurons, correct_output)
        self.hiddenLayerErrors = np.multiply(np.dot(self.secondLayerWeights.T, self.outputLayerErrors), self.sigmoidDerivative(self.secondLayerNeurons))

        for i in range (self.dimensions[2]):
            for j in range (self.dimensions[1]):
                if j==0:
                    self.secondLayerBiasesSummations[i] += self.outputLayerErrors[i]
                self.secondLayerWeightsSummations[i][j] += self.outputLayerErrors[i]*self.secondLayerNeurons[j]
        for i in range (self.dimensions[1]):
            for j in range (self.dimensions[0]):
                if j==0:
                    self.firstLayerBiasesSummations[i] += self.hiddenLayerErrors[i]
                self.firstLayerWeightsSummations[i][j] += self.hiddenLayerErrors[i]*inputs[j]

    def train(self, trainImages, trainLabels):
        size = str(self.sizeOfEpoch)
        greatestError = 0.0

        for m in range (self.sizeOfEpoch):
            correct_output = np.zeros([self.dimensions[2]])
            correct_output[int(class_names[trainLabels[m]])] = 1.0

            self.forwardProp(trainImages[m].flatten())
            self.backProp(trainImages[m].flatten(), correct_output)

            if np.argmax(self.outputNeurons) == int(trainLabels[m]):
                self.correct+=1

            if m%150 == 0:
                error = np.amax(np.absolute(self.outputLayerErrors))
                if error > greatestError:
                    greatestError = error
                accuracy = str(int((self.correct/(m+1))*100)) + '%'
                percent = str(int((m/self.sizeOfEpoch)*100)) + '%'
                print ("Progress: " + percent + " -- Accuracy: " + accuracy + " -- Error: " + str(greatestError), end="\r")
        self.change()
        print (size + '/' + size + " -- " + " -- Accuracy: " + accuracy + " -- Error: " + str(greatestError), end="\r")
        self.correct = 0

    def change(self):
        for i in range (self.dimensions[2]):
            for j in range (self.dimensions[1]):
                if j == 0:
                    self.secondLayerBiases[i] -= self.learningRate*self.secondLayerBiasesSummations[i]
                self.secondLayerWeights[i][j] -= self.learningRate*(self.secondLayerWeightsSummations[i][j]+self.Lambda*self.secondLayerWeights[i][j])
        for i in range (self.dimensions[1]):
            for j in range (self.dimensions[0]):
                if j == 0:
                    self.firstLayerBiases[i] -= self.learningRate*self.firstLayerBiasesSummations[i]
                self.firstLayerWeights[i][j] -= self.learningRate*(self.firstLayerWeightsSummations[i][j]+self.Lambda*self.firstLayerWeights[i][j])

        self.firstLayerSummations = np.zeros([self.dimensions[1], self.dimensions[0]])
        self.secondLayerSummations = np.zeros([self.dimensions[2], self.dimensions[1]])
        self.firstLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros(self.dimensions[1])
        self.secondLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros(self.dimensions[2])
            
    def predict(self, testImage):
        secondLayerAnsNodes = np.empty([self.dimensions[1]])
        outputAns = np.empty([self.dimensions[2]])
        for i in range (self.dimensions[1]):
            secondLayerAnsNodes[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.firstLayerWeights[i], testImage)+self.firstLayerBiases[i])
        for i in range (self.dimensions[2]):
            outputAns[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.secondLayerWeights[i], secondLayerAnsNodes)+self.secondLayerBiases[i])
        return np.argmax(outputAns)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

    neural_network = NeuralNetwork([784, 10, 10], train_images.shape[0]-52000)

    for i in range (neural_network.epochs):
        print ("\nEpoch", str(i+1) + "/" + str(neural_network.epochs))
        neural_network.train(train_images, train_labels)
```

For some reason, this code does not work with more complicated problems. The error doesn't get minimized and the accuracy stays the same. This exact code works for the xor problem and another one similar to it. When I try and give it the MNIST dataset of numbers, it doesn't work. The only difference is that there are more nodes in each layer, the algorithm is the same.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Is it just me or does your backprop formula not account for the sigmoid activation function (i.e. it's as if it was just y=bias+x*weights), so the derivatives are all wrong?

Comment: @Peteris I'm a bit confused about what you're saying. There isn't a sigmoid in the derivatives. The backdrop just sums up all my derivatives, there is a derivative of the sigmoid in the whole derivative though.